# Call Web Service from jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have tried to call webservice method using ajax in asp.net.
This is my web service method.

```
[WebMethod]
public String registerWS(String email, String firstname, String lastname, String address, String mobile)
{
    String query = "insertcrud_sp";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    String res = "";
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobile);
    con.Open();
        if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            con.Close();
            res= "true";
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            res= "false";
        }
    return res;
}
```

This is my jquery code..

```
$(document).on("click","#btnajaxcontrol", function () {
    var mail = document.getElementById("txtmail").value;
    var fname = document.getElementById("txtfname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("txtlname").value;
    var addr = document.getElementById("txtaddress").value;
    var mobile = document.getElementById("txtmobile").value;
    if (ValidateEmail(mail) && !(mail == "") && !(fname == "") && !(lname == "") && !(addr == "") && !(mobile == "")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "CRUDwebserviceJS.asmx/registerWS",
            data: { 'email': mail, 'firstname': fname, 'lastname': lname, 'address': addr, 'mobile': mobile },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var wsres = data.d;
                if (wsres == 'true') {
                    $('#lblmsg').html('User Successfully Registered...');
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                $('#lblmsg').html('User Registeration faild...!');
                $("#lblmsg").css('background', 'red');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Web service method works alone... but when i am calling web service from ajax the error message only invoked... I don't know whats wrong with my code.. please help me to find out what error in my program and suggest what i need to change.... Thanks in advanced....

Comment: try the error method as follows `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }` and see what is the error you are getting. you can also use `xhr.responseText`

Comment: add a breakpoint to ur web mthod and see if it is hit on post call.

Comment: now its show internal server err...What to do now....

Comment: thanks friends.. I fixed the problem by uncomment the following line : [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]